# Could the Half-Blood Prince have come up with an antidote to dozen different love potions at once?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry and Hermione are discussing some younger students who want to give Harry a love potion. Hermione states,

> "As I doubt whether even the Half-Blood Prince" -- she gave the book another nasty look-- "could dream up an antidote for a dozen different love potions at once."

Is this fair of Hermione to say? Could the Half-Blood Prince have come up with an antidote?

Comment: I'm sure he could -- he was a talented potions professor.  Is it fair of her to say?  Well, she was clearly jealous of the book (or rather, the HBP's notes), so it was most likely said out of envy/spite.  However, she would have never made that comment if she knew who was writing those notes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering that we know that Half-Blood Prince is

> Severus Snape

... he can.

> "A bezoar is a stone taken from the stomach of a goat and **it will save you from most poisons**. (*Philosopher's Stone*)

Leaving the lifehack option out, the answer is we don't know. Probably, with enough research, he might have, for **any givent combination of love potions** - but not for a generic, random, unknown-in-advance combination.

The main thing preventing him would be:

- Golpalott's Third Law

  > "The antidote for a blended poison will be equal to more than the sum of the antidotes for each of the separate components."
- The fact that presumably, some antidote components may not play well with OTHER antidote components. We see that in Muggle drugs.

Comment: ps i think theirs a quote in hbp in his potions book about a bezoar too

Comment: He's [Spoiler] F'in [Spoiler]! He can do *anything*!